# how to solve 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'

Tags: javascript, html

in my script.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.1/firebase-app.js";
 import { getDatabase, ref, set, child, get } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.4.1/firebase-database.js";


 // Initialize Firebase
 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const db = getDatabase(app);
 const dbRef = ref(db);
```

is showing error SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
how do I solve this

Comment: There *has* to be a good dupetarget for this but I'm struggling to find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using `import` in a script, not a module. The distinction is in how the environment was told to load the file.

In a browser, you need `type="module"` on the `script` tag:

```html
<script src="./script.js" type="module"></script>
```

More [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

On Node.js, you need `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` or the `.mjs` extension, see [the Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) for details.